# validate alphanumeric value in UITextField

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I want alphanumeric value in textfield.If user enter only character or number then sending massage.Even no special characters acceptable.

```
        NSString *str = askIdTxt.text;
        NSCharacterSet *alphanumericSet = [NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet];
        NSCharacterSet *numberSet = [NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet];
        BOOL isAlphaNumericOnly = [[str stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:alphanumericSet] isEqualToString:@""] && ! [[str stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:numberSet] isEqualToString:@""];
        if (isAlphaNumericOnly) {
             NSLog(@"isAplhaNumericOnly: %@",(isAlphaNumericOnly? @"Yes":@"No"));
        }
```

This is always returning true. I am not getting what is wrong in this.

Comment: Try using NSNumberFormatter and convert the string to a number. If that returns nil then it is not a number according to the format that you are using.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about using regular expression:

```
-(BOOL)isAlphaNumericOnly:(NSString *)input 
{
    NSString *alphaNum = @"[a-zA-Z0-9]+";
    NSPredicate *regexTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", alphaNum];

    return [regexTest evaluateWithObject:input];
}
```

and then use it

```
if([self isAlphaNumeric:str])
{
    NSLog(@"IT IS ALPHA NUMERIC STRING");

}
```

**edit**
The same technique can be used to validate passwords, you need only better regex:

```
-(BOOL)isPasswordStrong:(NSString *)password {
/*
8-20 chars
at least one letter
at least one number OR special character
no more than 3 repeated characters
*/
        NSString *strongPass= @"^(?!.*(.)\\1{3})((?=.*[\\d])(?=.*[A-Za-z])|(?=.*[^\\w\\d\\s])(?=.*[A-Za-z])).{8,20}$";;
        NSPredicate *regexTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", strongPass];

        return [regexTest evaluateWithObject:password];
}
```

using the regular expression you can create different rules but this can give you a headstart,

Comment: Where can I find documentation on what @"^(?!.*(.)\\1{3})((?=.*[\\d])(?=.*[A-Za-z])|(?=.*[^\\w\\d\\s])(?=.*[A-Za-z])).{8,20}$" means? I would like to use this in the future but unfortunately I am unable to decipher what each part means. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
 Call this Method and modify it accordingly .....


   -(BOOL) isPasswordValid:(NSString *)pwd 
     {

       if ( [pwd length]<4 || [pwd length]>20 ) return NO;  // too long or too short
       NSRange rang;
       rang = [pwd rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet]];
       if ( !rang.length ) return NO;  // no letter
       rang = [pwd rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet]];
       if ( !rang.length )  return NO;  // no number;
       return YES;

     }
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess the problem is in the `alphanumericCharacterSet`, here is [a part from doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nscharacterset_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSCharacterSet/decimalDigitCharacterSet):

> Informally, this set is the set of all characters used as basic units
>   of alphabets, syllabaries, ideographs, and digits.

So, I am expecting it would allow the unwanted characters to you.

You may also try using Regex:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"^[a-z\\d]+$" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
NSUInteger matches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:str options:NSMatchingReportCompletion range:NSMakeRange(0, [str length])];

BOOL hasMatches = (matches > 0) && !error;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

        NSCharacterSet *charactersToBlock = [[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet] invertedSet];
        return ([string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:charactersToBlock].location == NSNotFound);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
NSCharacterSet *blockedCharacters = [[[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet] invertedSet] retain];

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)field shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)characters
{
    return ([characters rangeOfCharacterFromSet:blockedCharacters].location == NSNotFound);
}
```